# Review queues and Association Bonuses

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users

I've been wondering: do the review queues cover questions from users who have a +100 rep association bonus, and if not, should they? I've seen review queues cleared before, and in some cases people don't post the famous
"Welcome to WorldBuilding _______! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!"

(I'm usually not comfortable enough to immediately answer/edit a question, but one of the ways I try to contribute is simply by guiding new users around the site.)

I think more could be done to ensure even users with the association bonus get these guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone who posts for the first time on WorldBuilding goes into the "First Post" review queue. Everyone. I've written [Welcome to WorldBuilding comments](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5254/28789) to people that are mods on other sites. Even employees from StackExchange, who automatically have mod privileges on all sites they visit, would go into those review queues with their first posts (you would see their diamond next to their username though).

Additionally anyone who has only posted a couple times (three times or so?) and answeres a question that has been inactive for a long time (half a year or so?) goes into the "Late Answer" review queue.

But it's up to every reviewer to decide what to do and what not to do. I like to leave such comments (further explanation in the link above) as I've also seen lots of users with 300 or 400 rep on other sites who didn't know about the tour and help center, but nobody is required. You can also simply click "Nothing to do" when you think it's all fine.

Ideally users with the association bonus would already know about those resources from their "home site", but in reality this may or may not be the case. Welcoming them and pointing them to valuable resources is a good thing to do, especially because WorldBuilding can be even weirder than other sites on the network.

Comment: LOL. This is coincidentally funny, since I use your main guideline for "Welcome to WorldBuilding" constantly. No need to link: I have that one bookmarked.