# Is this on-topic? (How to slay a creature with a "healing factor")

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I was planning to write a question about how a creature with a mutant healing factor -- a la marvel comics -- could be slain.  I plan to describe the creature, it's attributes, then the proposed method of killing it.

(Please do be aware that this is a last resort; many attempts at negotiation, cultural exchange, and detente have failed.  It is necessary.)

**Is this worldbuild-y enough to be on topic here?**  It's kind of the opposite of the usual xenobiology question, which leans toward *building* a creature, while I, from sad necessity, plan to ... **un**-build it.

Comment: I see you have participated in discussion about our [question sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4835/29). Any particular reason you're posting this separately rather than using the sandbox?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling  Yep!  The question would take a bit of research and a good deal of time to prepare, even for submission to sandbox.  I don't fancy doing that if odds are high that such a question is just off-topic, and not fixable.  This is just a sanity-check.

Answer (score 4):

This is highly dependent upon the specifics of the question you are asking.

Personally I think that asking "If a creature had a healing factor that worked by mechanism X would it be wounded by Y?" would be neither too story based or too broad provided that mechanism X is described in sufficient detail.

Asking "Could someone with super healing be wounded by Y?" is probably too broad because we don't know the mechanism of the super healing. Without knowing the mechanism "It will if you say it does." is a technically correct, though a cop-out, answer.

Asking "What could wound a creature with a healing factor that works by mechanism X?" is harder to determine whether it is a good fit or not. It feels like it's probably too broad and too much of an idea generation question to me.

Without knowing of the specifics of the question you are wanting to ask I can't say whether it's fundamentally flawed or can be made into a good question by specific editing.

Answer (score 1):

We've dealt with a few [unstoppable enemies](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/what-to-do-about-unstoppable-questions), they've mostly gone through but what's happened in the past may not happen again as theoretically they're all either too broad, opinion, or story based.